# R (dplyr): Sum list of values relative to first value in list

Tags: r, dplyr

In the `DATA` table below I have a list of numbers that belong to three groups `A`, `B`, and `C`. I need to create another column `NAYSA`, that contains the sum of two numbers relative to the first number in the group. Not all groups have multiple numbers in my data set. Hopefully the `RESULT` table illustrates what I need to do.

Notice the first row for each group in the `NAYSA` column is the same as in the `YRS` column in the `DATA` table. However, row 3 in the `NAYSA` column is sum of values from rows 2 and 3 in the `YRS` column. Similarly, rows 5 and 6 in `NAYSA` are the sum of values from rows 4 and 5; and  4 and 6 in the `YRS` column, respectively.

I prefer solutions using `dplyr` but am open to other suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
DATA = data.frame(IND = c("A","B","B","C","C","C"), 
                  YRS = c("1","10","20","100","1","10"))

RESULT = data.frame(IND = c("A","B","B","C","C","C"), 
                    YRS = c("1","10","20","100","1","10"), 
                    NAYSA = c(1, 10, 30, 100, 101, 110))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `dplyr` solution matches your expected result:

```
library(dplyr)
RESULT <- DATA  %>%
  # set the grouping factor 
  group_by(IND) %>%
  # convert YRS to numeric and generate new variable by adding the
  # first value on the YRS column to YRS on the current row, unless
  # we are on the first row, in that case just keep the current value 
  # of YRS 
  mutate(YRS = as.numeric(as.character(YRS)),
         NAYSA = ifelse(row_number() == 1, YRS, first(YRS) + YRS))

> RESULT
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: IND [3]

      IND   YRS NAYSA
  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)
1      A     1     1
2      B    10    10
3      B    20    30
4      C   100   100
5      C     1   101
6      C    10   110
```

One caveat of this solution is that is doesn't match the data types in your expected result, but I'm not sure the data types in your example is what you want.

I realize this answer is very similar to the one provided by @Gopala but I think using `first` instead of an index makes the code more clear, also, I used `as.numeric` instead of `as.integer` because I feel is a more general approach.

I hope you find this solution useful.

Comment: Thanks @Gopala and @donlelek! This code is exactly what I need. Every time I ask a question here I learn a new approach....`ifelse` and 'first' functions. Sorry for the confusion with the `YRS` column, I accidentally entered it as a character rather than a numeric. Take care.

Answer (score 3):

Editing to match required output you can use `mutate` like this:

```
DATA$YRS <- as.integer(as.character(DATA$YRS))
DATA %>% group_by(IND) %>% mutate(NAYSA = ifelse(row_number() == 1, YRS, YRS + YRS[1]))
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: IND [3]

     IND   YRS NAYSA
  (fctr) (int) (int)
1      A     1     1
2      B    10    10
3      B    20    30
4      C   100   100
5      C     1   101
6      C    10   111
```

BTW - I had to convert YRS to integer first as you created that column as character vector in your data set. Of course, you don't need this step if your original data in this column is already in numeric format.

Comment: This looks good but since you're already using a dplyr pipe, why don't you make the conversion from character/factor to numeric inside the `mutate` step?

Comment: Upon reading the question again, I think they want a slightly different result (check the 111 vs 110).

Comment: You are correct about expected output. Modified the code. I did not use factor conversion in the pipe because I was not sure if the 'real' data has this issue or not from the posted sample data.